# UITableViewCell dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is not in order

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I have a UITable with few custom cells which contains text fields. However when up scroll up and down the the order of those cells are messed up.

I searched and this is not working for me cos I have few UITextFields where I need to grab user inputs for those.

[UITableViewCell showing indexpath rows out of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592586/uitableviewcell-showing-indexpath-rows-out-of-order)

Thank You

Comment: You should watch the WWDC 2010 session 128, Mastering Table Views. Search for it on Google. The problem is that table cells are reusable, since often each row in the table is visually the same, but with different content. You need to make sure that the table cell you return contains the correct data for the index path requested, not just any row. Watch the video to get more details and example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to use a unique identifier for each of the cells, or else avoid using the dequeuing mechanism altogether. If you're doing the latter, store a reference to each cell in a corresponding instance variable, or else add them all to a collection stored in an instance variable.

If you decide to go this route, you could do this one of two ways: either create the cells in Interface Builder (which would be handy, because they could already have the text fields nested inside them, nicely positioned, etc.) and connect them using outlets, or create the cells programmatically in `viewDidLoad` or in an `init...` method.

In either case, you would no longer need to call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`; instead you could just return the cell instances you've already created.

Comment: Yes I had to implement my unique way of doing dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier according to my requirement. That solved the problem. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: You're welcome! So did you end up using a unique identifier for each cell?

Answer (score 0):

@Dilshan you can do something similar to this in your code to achieve what you want.

```
.
.
.
if(cell == nil)
{
// create your cell in this block of quotes in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method to avoid making of the cells again, so that your textfield value remain as it is.
.
.
.
//place all the code in this block only.
}
[cell autorelease];
return cell;
```

sorry i don't have xcode at home so i can't give you any specific code.

but i think you get the idea .
cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do following. See my next post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code. CustomTextFieldCell is a cell with a UITextField. and some info. However the populated value and the order of those changes when you scroll.

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTextFieldCell";
    CustomTextFieldCell *cell = (CustomTextFieldCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTextFieldCell" owner:nil options:nil];


        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (CustomTextFieldCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a note -- it's better to add supplementary info by editing the original question rather than posting it as an answer.